# How to have a control to select a picture from local path instead of server on Infopath form

Tags: 2013, infopath

Searched far and wide on Google for this..

Would really like to have a Picture column/control work like an Attachment column control, in that a user can select from local path instead of needing to upload to a separate library and then link.

Current:

[image: Currently]

Preferred:

[image: Preferred]

I understand there are probably mechanical differences in how the files are handled by the server and where they are stored, but I would really like if the user could select from local path for the picture control.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OOTB SharePoint does not provide this functionality but there are several third party tools available for this.

[This link](http://sparqubepicturelite.codeplex.com/) provides an Open Source solution to requirement in question.

It will basically create a custom column which will allow to upload picture from local drive.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in InfoPath like that, your best choice is to use **Attachment** control, which will allow you to navigate into your local folder.